# Select same / select similar in ArcGIS

Tags: arcgis-desktop, select

Can a "select similar" right click (**two** clicks total) like in [AutoCad](http://forums.autodesk.com/t5/AutoCAD-2010-2011-2012/How-to-use-the-command-select-similar-to-be-applied/td-p/3369731) be created in ArcGIS as an addin or something python-related?
It is listed on their "ideas" page here:
[arcgis ideasSelect same/select similar](http://ideas.arcgis.com/ideaView?id=087300000008IfO&returnUrl=%2Fapex%2FideaList%3Fc%3D09a300000004xET%26category%3DBusiness%2BAnalyst%2B%253Fiframe%253Dtrue%26p%3D111)

[image]

Comment: Although you have provided a link to someone else's (I think) requirements that link could easily go stale so I think it would be better if you could edit your question to also include what your requirements are, and your use case(s) for such a function.

Comment: I agree with PolyGeo, perhaps provide more information about what you're trying to do and we can suggest work-arounds or tools. If you want to select similar shapes you could always set up a SQL query for objects that are a certain size.

Answer (score 1):

There is not anything in esri as nice as this autodesk (heads up) interface.
My Method to accomplish this in esri would be...

1. select by location. first select the polygon, then select by location and use the target layer to be selected. and the selection (checkbox) on the source.
   [image: select by location]
   Then using the select by attributes you can do a lot of iterations.
   It allows you to add to selection, remove from selection, select from selected.
   [image: select by attributes]
   As I said, not nearly the interface that autodesk has developed, but nonetheless it should get you what you need.

For strictly finding similar attributes the find dialog below.

[image: select similar]
there is a find similar option (checkbox).
You would need to right click and select once found.

Comment: Thanks Brad, this is helpful. Kind of looking for something a little more intuitive though like the AutoCAD Select Similar tool